# How to link external javascript file in Adobe Brackets IDE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, adobe-brackets

The code works in Codecademy but doesn't seem to work in [Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io/) IDE. Greatly appreciate any help on this issue!

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS File**

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

**Javascript File**

```
var main = function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $('div').hide();
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your folder structure. there is nothing to do with the editor when you are including js files.

one more thing your code seems a jQuery code and to make it run you will need
jQuery library file included before your script.js file. to use jQuery functions in your code you need to add the functions library first.

**check code below**

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally managed to get the code working! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RafflesAndrison: if you my answer is useful to you, you can accept it by ticking correct mark

Comment: How to refer internal js file, I added the script tag in the header, the file is not loaded in the browser, How to fix this

Comment: @GANI Can you show your code? without looking at what code you have, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You've not included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your document.

http://jquery.com/download/

Via CDN:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

If you open your JavaScript console you'd likely see an error telling you that `$` is not defined.

- [Chrome Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)
- [FireFox Developer Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console)